# UWP - Speech Recognition - Can't reference an external grammar file

Tags: parsing, uwp, speech-recognition, sfspeechrecognizer

I am building an UWP application with speech recognition capability. I want to reference an external grammar file from within another -root- file.
Here is the code for the root grammar file (named `RootGrammar.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="en-us" 
         root="topLevel" 
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" 
         tag-format="semantics/1.0"
         mode="voice">

<rule id="topLevel">
  <item>Hello</item>
  <ruleref uri="words.xml"/>
</rule>

</grammar>
```

And the external grammar file (named `words.xml`) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="en-us" root="words"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" 
         tag-format="semantics/1.0" 
         mode="voice">

  <rule id="words" scope="public">
    <one-of>
      <item>world</item>
      <item>universe</item>
      <item>galaxy</item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>

</grammar>
```

The two files are located in the same folder (named `Grammar`), the folder is located on the top level of the solution.

I tried many values for the URI attribute in the root grammar file like:

- `uri= "/words.xml"`
- `uri= "\words.xml"`
- `uri = "../words.xml"`
- `uri = "..\words.xml"`
- `uri = "ms-appx:///Grammar///words.xml"`

I also tried to rename the external file into `words.grxml`, also tried explicitly identify the rule in the uri (i.e `uri = "/words.xml#words"`) but all of that resulted in `GrammarCompilationFailure`.

Comment: is `BuildAction` set properly for the file `words.xml`? Also, try `uri= "words.xml"`.

Comment: @MohamedMokhtar I could reproduce this question. I've reported to the relevant team. They're now investigating this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design. When checking the file path references, the only supported URI schemes are `file://`, `http://`, and `https://`. For now, the only solution will likely be to not have external reference files. You also could submit a **Feature Request** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the file as a **Content** file. Select the file in the **Solution Explorer** and in the **Properties** window set the **Build Action** to **Content**.

Then, the proper URI should be:

```
ms-appx:///Grammar/words.xml
```

Only the root is three forward slashes (`///`), then you just use single slash (`/`).

Comment: The **Build Action** is set to **content** for both files. I tried the suggested URI but it still does not work.

Comment: If you move  the rule in the root file (without referencing the other file), does it work?